# Angularjs ng-repeat error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using Angularjs I can't do ng-repeat. First ng-repeat is working fine next is not working fine

Html code

```
<div class="col-xs-12" ng-app="myAns" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<table class="table">
<tr><td ng-repeat="fullname in team1_name">{{fullname}}</td></tr>
    <tr><td ng-repeat="strike in team1_strike">{{strike}}</td></tr>
    <tr><td ng-repeat="wickets in team1_wickets">{{wickets}}</td></tr> 
</table>
</div>
```

Js code

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myAns', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $timeout(function() {
    $http({
        url: 'cricketAnswerSuggestionApi.php',
        method: "POST",
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        }
    }).then(function (response) { 
            $scope.team1_name = response.data.team_1.fullname;
            $scope.team1_strike = response.data.team_1.strike_rate;
            $scope.team1_wickets = response.data.team_1.wickets;
        });
    });
    });
</script>
```

JSON response link

https://jsfiddle.net/rijo/aapfa0sL/

Kindly anyone help how to print this value using angularjs ... Thanks for all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have some duplicate data

Use `track by $index` for **`team1_strike`** and **`team1_wickets`**

Try this,

```
 <div class="col-xs-12" ng-app="myAns" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="fullname in team1_name">{{fullname}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="strike in team1_strike track by $index">{{strike}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="wickets in team1_wickets track by $index">{{wickets}}</td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/o3ZT9ECuS7ArzFA2vzpw?p=preview)**

Comment: @nikky who said i did? probably because you have posted the same

Comment: i was using `track by $index` for first ng-repeat also.it doesnt make any difference from your answer?Will it work with your answer if `team1_name` have duplicates?